# HTTP/HTTPS duplicate content 301 vs canonical

Tags: 301-redirect, https, duplicate-content, canonical-url, http

I thought I would ask a question as the amount of different sources that say this is right or that isn't right is unbelievable.

Let me tell you my situation, at the moment, my boss wanted me to add SSL to the website, to get the green padlock more or less. I've done this, while also using *.htaccess* file to force HTTPS.

The main problem is that Google is seeing `http://site.co.uk` and `https://site.co.uk` and is indexing them.

Will the page rank carry over from `http://site.co.uk` to `https://site.co.uk` using a permemant 301 redirection or would a canonical set to `https://site.co.uk` work just as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends if you want the site to be accessible via both `http` and `https`. (This may be the case if you only want `https` active once users login).

If you **don't** need both `http` and `https` accessible then a 301 redirect from `http` and `https` is the correct thing to do.

301 redirects are preferable, as they will carry over most of the PageRank and canonical tags are only a hint to Google, not an absolute directive, [although they do try to follow them where possible](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394)

If you **do** however need **both** `http` and `https` accessible then canonical tags would be the correct thing to do, as if you set 301 redirects, `http` wont be accessible as they will redirect to `https`

Also, ensure  to reflect your redirects or canonicals in your sites internal linking and sitemap.xml file. - Stick to one type of linking, e.g all link are defined with https in site structure and in the sitemap.xml file.

Comment: We have a payment section on our website, that is fully secure through https, although my boss want's the green padlock on all major pages. What would you suggest in this situation?

Comment: redirects from http to https and make sure site structure is linking with https and URLs in sitemap.xml use https.

Comment: Ok thanks alot for the help, would doing it this way also solve the duplicate content between http://site and https://site?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking in that comment? Do you mean http and https again?

Comment: Sorry Yes duplicate content between http and https

Comment: Yes the redirect will solve this.

Comment: Why would some people **still** want to keep the HTTP version if the secure HTTPS version is already available?